# Filter field received from rest service using RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate

I am using `spring RestTemplate` to get data from rest service. The service return list of `User` object

```
public Class User{

private String userId;
private String firstName;
private String lastName
//other fields
//getter setter

}
```

As a client i am only interested on `userId` field and i don't need other fields. 
How can i filter all other properties and only get list of `userId`.

**Note:**

1. Rest service doesn't have filter provision.
2. I don't want to create a class with only `userId` as parameter and use annotation `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` and map response to this class

Is there a way to do this.

Comment: i don't know why you are away with option 2

Comment: what exactly is wrong with option 2? you do not want to create a new class or to use `@JsonIgnoreProperties` annotation?

Comment: So there is no better solution than option 2 ?

Answer (score 0):

Read about `JsonNode`. Then try to retrieve particular key (userId) for every `User` object. Otherwise you could try make custom Jackson deserializer.

Comment: Could you please elaborate your answer.

Comment: Read [this](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization) - custom deserializer point. You could use `@JsonDeserialize` annotation too.